# Java, Spark and Cassandra java.lang.ClassCastException: com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture cannot be cast to shade

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra

I got an error trying to write data to my Cassandra database.

What I got here:
1) Dictionary.java

```
package com.chatSparkConnactionTest;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Dictionary implements Serializable{
private String value_id;
private String d_name;
private String d_value;

public Dictionary(){}

public Dictionary (String value_id, String d_name, String d_value) {
    this.setValue_id(value_id);
    this.setD_name(d_name);
    this.setD_value(d_value);
}

public String getValue_id() {
    return value_id;
}
public void setValue_id(String value_id) {
    this.value_id = value_id;
}
public String getD_name() {
    return d_name;
}
public void setD_name(String d_name) {
    this.d_name = d_name;
}
public String getD_value() {
    return d_value;
}
public void setD_value(String d_value) {
    this.d_value = d_value;
   }
}
```

My main class:

```
package com.chatSparkConnactionTest;

import static com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions;
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;

import com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil;
import com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraRow;
import com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.SparkContextJavaFunctions;
import com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.rdd.CassandraJavaRDD;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector;
import com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraRow;
import com.google.common.base.Objects;

import org.apache.avro.data.Json;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
//import org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD;
//import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLContext;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import static com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions;
import static com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.mapRowTo;
import static com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.mapToRow;
import com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraRow;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode; 
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function; 


public class JavaDemoRDDWrite implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().
            setAppName("chat").
            setMaster("local").
            set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        List<Dictionary> dictionary = Arrays.asList(
                new Dictionary("7", "n1", "v1"),
                new Dictionary("8", "n2", "v2"),
                new Dictionary("9", "n3", "v3")
        );
        for (Dictionary dictionaryRow : dictionary) {
            System.out.println("id: " + dictionaryRow.getValue_id());
            System.out.println("name: " + dictionaryRow.getD_name());
            System.out.println("value: " + dictionaryRow.getD_value());
        }

        JavaRDD<Dictionary> rdd = sc.parallelize(dictionary);
        System.out.println("Total rdd rows: " + rdd.collect().size());
        javaFunctions(rdd)
        .writerBuilder("chat", "dictionary", 
                mapToRow(Dictionary.class))
        .saveToCassandra();

    };
}
```

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>chat_connaction_test</groupId>
  <artifactId>ChatSparkConnectionTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <dependencies> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-M3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

And here is the error text:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture cannot be cast to shade.com.datastax.spark.connector.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncExecutor.executeAsync(AsyncExecutor.scala:31)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(TableWriter.scala:159)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(TableWriter.scala:158)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.GroupingBatchBuilder.foreach(GroupingBatchBuilder.scala:31)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:158)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:135)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.closeResourceAfterUse(CassandraConnector.scala:140)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.write(TableWriter.scala:135)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:37)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
16/10/11 17:43:03 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture cannot be cast to shade.com.datastax.spark.connector.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncExecutor.executeAsync(AsyncExecutor.scala:31)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(TableWriter.scala:159)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(TableWriter.scala:158)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.GroupingBatchBuilder.foreach(GroupingBatchBuilder.scala:31)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:158)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:135)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.closeResourceAfterUse(CassandraConnector.scala:140)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.write(TableWriter.scala:135)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:37)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

16/10/11 17:43:03 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
16/10/11 17:43:03 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
16/10/11 17:43:03 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 1
16/10/11 17:43:03 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 1 (runJob at RDDFunctions.scala:37) failed in 0.274 s
16/10/11 17:43:03 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1 failed: runJob at RDDFunctions.scala:37, took 0.291592 s
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture cannot be cast to shade.com.datastax.spark.connector.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncExecutor.executeAsync(AsyncExecutor.scala:31)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(TableWriter.scala:159)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(TableWriter.scala:158)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.GroupingBatchBuilder.foreach(GroupingBatchBuilder.scala:31)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:158)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:135)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.closeResourceAfterUse(CassandraConnector.scala:140)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.write(TableWriter.scala:135)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:37)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1438)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1659)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1618)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1607)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1871)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1884)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1904)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions.saveToCassandra(RDDFunctions.scala:37)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.RDDJavaFunctions.saveToCassandra(RDDJavaFunctions.java:61)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.RDDAndDStreamCommonJavaFunctions$WriterBuilder.saveToCassandra(RDDAndDStreamCommonJavaFunctions.java:486)
    at com.chatSparkConnactionTest.JavaDemoRDDWrite.main(JavaDemoRDDWrite.java:69)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture cannot be cast to shade.com.datastax.spark.connector.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncExecutor.executeAsync(AsyncExecutor.scala:31)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(TableWriter.scala:159)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(TableWriter.scala:158)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.GroupingBatchBuilder.foreach(GroupingBatchBuilder.scala:31)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:158)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:135)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.closeResourceAfterUse(CassandraConnector.scala:140)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.write(TableWriter.scala:135)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:37)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**The thing is that system inserts first value from the RDD to database table as a result even if I got an error.** And other 2 rows just ignored.

But, just in case, this is my Cassandra table:

```
CREATE TABLE dictionary (
  value_id    text,
  d_value     text, 
  d_name    text,
  PRIMARY KEY (value_id, d_name)
) WITH comment = 'dictionary values'
AND CLUSTERING ORDER BY (d_name ASC);
```

Updated pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>chat_connaction_test</groupId>
  <artifactId>ChatSparkConnectionTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <dependencies> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-M3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Just curious if you've found solution for this problem. It's Spark 2.1.0, spark-cassandra-connector 2.0.1 and exactly the same problem as you described.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove below "cassandra-driver-core" dependency from your pom.xml file as it is causing the issue. You only need "spark-cassandra-connector" dependency along with spark dependencies in order to interact with Cassandra DB.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried, same result: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture cannot be cast to shade.com.datastax.spark.connector.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture

Comment: Did you update maven project and clean build. I tested your code and it is working fine. Issue was that dependency. Try clean build.

Comment: I just cleaned it, but still got an error. I just opened a Java compiler and changed JDK version to 1.8 but no effect :(

Comment: I can reproduce exact same error by including that dependency. If I remove that dependency everything works fine. So please check your environment and make sure cassandra-driver-core-3.1.0.jar is not present anywhere.

Comment: Oh, yep. I just made a new one maven project and it was perfectly working. So, I just excluded all jars from initial one, all fixed, thank you, I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: @AlekseyKiselev, it seems "made a new one maven project" is the key.

Comment: I was not able to remove this driver, instead, I placed it in maven dependencies under the spark-cassandra-connector dependency. Maven magic ;)

Comment: @BdLearner I am having the same issue as you. Were you able to find a solution?